# Pandas date overlap

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a reasonably difficult question that has been bugging me for a few days involving a pandas dataframe.

Lets say I have a dataframe with around 100,000 rows with the following columns:

```
member_id, p1_start, p1_end, p2_start, and p2_end.
```

Basically from this dataframe I would like to extract a subset that includes all rows that have duplicate `member_ids`. Within this subset I would like to specifically select the `member_ids` whose `p1_start` is between any other `member_ids` `p1_start` and `p2_end`.

Does anyone have a good idea about how to do this?

Here is an example of what the dataframe looks like.

```
    member_id   p2_start    p2_end  p3_start    p3_end
0   100042881   2013-03-25  2013-03-26  2013-03-26  2013-06-23
1   100085837   2012-09-24  2012-10-02  2012-10-02  2012-12-30
2   100086649   2014-02-17  2014-02-20  2014-02-20  2014-05-20
3   100091388   2014-10-18  2014-10-25  2014-10-25  2015-01-22
4   100273057   2013-03-06  2013-03-09  2013-03-09  2013-06-06
```

I would like to create an additional column that marks whether or not the row is an overlap row.

Comment: It would help if you included a [MCVE].

Comment: Your example would be more useful if it included data that could be used for your problem (i.e. with duplicate ids) and if you also had an example of the output you wanted from it.